# Count distinct items in teradata result set

Tags: sql, teradata

I am building a report to display sales at a product level, and need to include a count of stores which have sold each product. My sales data is broken down by weeks, but I also need to include service level statistics which is at daily level.

The problem I am having is that when I try to count the number of stores each product is sold in, it is being multiplied by up to 7 times (depending how many days of the week there is a service level record for), so my question is can I get a distinct count of stores within the one query.

The data is structured as follows:

**Sales data**

```
WeekNo   StoreNo   ProductNo   SalesValue
201301   123       123456       10,000.00
201301   123       654321        5,000.00
201301   124       123456        9,400.00
201301   124       654321        3,500.00
201302   123       123456       11,500.00
etc.
```

**Service Level data** *Joined to sales via a table which converts calendar date to WeekNo*

```
Date         StoreNo   ProductNo   ServiceLevel
01/01/2013   123       123456                99
03/01/2013   123       123456                98
04/01/2013   123       123456               100
etc.
```

My SQL is as follows:

```
 select sales.ProductNo,
        prod.ProductDesc,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201330 then 1 end) as StoresSoldInThisWeek,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201329 then 1 end) as StoresSoldInLastWeek,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then 1 end) / 4 as StoresSoldInAverage,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201330 then sales.SalesValue end) as SalesValueThisWeek,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201329 then sales.SalesValue end) as SalesValueLastWeek,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then wks.SalesValue end) / 4 as SalesValueAverage,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201330 then sales.SalesVolume end) as SalesVolumeThisWeek,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201329 then sales.SalesVolume end) as SalseVolumeLastWeek,
        sum(case when sales.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then sales.SalesVolume end) / 4 as SalesVolumeAverage,
        cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo = 201330 then serv.Delivered end) as float) / nullifzero(cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo = 201330 then serv.Ordered end) as float)) as ServiceLevelThisWeek,
        cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo = 201329 then serv.Delivered end) as float) / nullifzero(cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo = 201329 then serv.Ordered end) as float)) as ServiceLevelLastWeek,
        cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then serv.Delivered end) as float) / nullifzero(cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then serv.Ordered end) as float)) as ServiceLevelAverage

   from Products prod
        inner join Sales sales
                on prod.ProductNo = sales.ProductNo
               and sales.WeekNo in (201324,201325,201326,201327,201329,201330)
         left join ServiceLevel serv
                on sales.ProductNo = serv.ProductNo
               and sales.StoreNo = serv.StoreNo
         left join Weeks week
                on serv.CalDate between week.WeekStartDate and week.WeekEndDate
               and sales.WeekNo = week.WeekNo

group by 1,2

order by 1
```

My attempt to get number of stores each product is sold in is:

```
sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201302 then 1 end) as StoresSoldInThisWeek,
sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201301 then 1 end) as StoresSoldInLastWeek,
```

I have tried summarising the Service Level data into weeks however this causes the query to take too long to run, so my question is what is the most efficient way of getting a distinct count of stores? I suspect this needs the ROW_NUMBER() function, but it doesn't seem to like me doing that in a Group By field

Comment: Without knowing the actual select it's hard to tell, it might be a COUNT(DISTINCT StoreNo) or a Derived Table to count before the join or a OLAP-function like ROW_NUMBER, or....

Comment: OK thanks, I've updated the question with the SQL. I'd tried count(distinct StoreNo) but it just returns 1 or 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all i think your current approach doesn't calculate the right values for other columns, too. E.g. each SalesValue will be summed up once per ServiceLevel row:

```
sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201330 then sales.SalesValue end) as SalesValueThisWeek,
```

You need to aggregate before the join, thus avoid joining the same row multiple times. 
This is how i would do that (i don't know if it actually fits your needs):

```
select sales.ProductNo,
        prod.ProductDesc,
        sales.StoresSoldInThisWeek,
        sales.StoresSoldInLastWeek,
        sales.StoresSoldInAverage,
        sales.SalesValueThisWeek,
        sales.SalesValueLastWeek,
        sales.SalesValueAverage,
        sales.SalesVolumeThisWeek,
        sales.SalseVolumeLastWeek,
        sales.SalesVolumeAverage,
        serv.ServiceLevelThisWeek,
        serv.ServiceLevelLastWeek,
        serv.ServiceLevelAverage
   from Products prod
   inner join
    ( -- you only use columns from sales, so all the calculations can be done without joins
      select
         sales.ProductNo,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201330 then 1 end) as StoresSoldInThisWeek,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201329 then 1 end) as StoresSoldInLastWeek,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then 1 end) / 4 as StoresSoldInAverage,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201330 then sales.SalesValue end) as SalesValueThisWeek,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201329 then sales.SalesValue end) as SalesValueLastWeek,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then wks.SalesValue end) / 4 as SalesValueAverage,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201330 then sales.SalesVolume end) as SalesVolumeThisWeek,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo = 201329 then sales.SalesVolume end) as SalseVolumeLastWeek,
         sum(case when sales.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then sales.SalesVolume end) / 4 as SalesVolumeAverage
      from Sales sales
      where sales.WeekNo in (201324,201325,201326,201327,201329,201330)
      group by 1
    ) sales
   on prod.ProductNo = sales.ProductNo
   left join -- do you really need an Outer Join?
    ( -- join Weeks and ServiceLevel 
      select
         serv.ProductNo,
         cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo = 201330 then serv.Delivered end) as float) 
           / nullifzero(cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo = 201330 then serv.Ordered end) as float)) as ServiceLevelThisWeek,
         cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo = 201329 then serv.Delivered end) as float) 
           / nullifzero(cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo = 201329 then serv.Ordered end) as float)) as ServiceLevelLastWeek,
         cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then serv.Delivered end) as float) 
           / nullifzero(cast(sum(case when serv.WeekNo between 201324 and 201327 then serv.Ordered end) as float)) as ServiceLevelAverage
      from ServiceLevel serv
      inner join Weeks week
              on serv.CalDate between week.WeekStartDate and week.WeekEndDate
      where weeks.WeekNo in (201324,201325,201326,201327,201329,201330)
      group by 1
    ) serv        
   on sales.ProductNo = serv.ProductNo
```

Comment: That's great, many thanks. You are of course correct about the other columns, don't I feel like an idiot now! But appreciate your help with this